# Is it possible to update a database record using RJS in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, prototype, ruby-on-rails-3

What I mean is if I can use, in someway, code like

```
page.replace_html :test, :partial => "/accounts/edit"
page.visual_effect(:appear, "test", :duration => 0.5)
...
```

to update a database record. If it isn't possible in that way, how is it possible?

Answer (score 3):

When you are hitting your RJS file the corresponding action in your controller is being called. This means if your file is my_method.js.rjs then my_controller.my_method is being called. You can put your database update statement in there.

I assume you want to update your database based on parameters passed through from the form, so params hash will allow you access to them from within the controller method.

Hope that answers your question.

Comment: I didn't understand it at all. Can you make an example? Are you saying that you can call a method in the controller from a '. js.rjs' file? Isit possible?

Comment: Sure. If you have a look at the example on http://railscasts.com/episodes/43-ajax-with-rjs you can see there are a few different parts to it - the rjs, the show view and the controller. When the remote form is submitted it goes to the controller action for the URL - in this case, create. When it hits the create definition in the reviews controller, it will then look for something to feed back to the user - in this case, because no create.html exists, it will use create.rjs. The values from the form you submit will be stored in params. Hopefully that clears up any confusion?

Answer (score 2):

Do the database access in whatever controller action calls this javascript builder. The javascript builder stuff is for the *view*.